# How do I get the return value of my __str__() function to print in my main?

Tags: python, class

I need to create two classes for a program that takes in input variable for a book, title, author, number of pages and looks to see if it's checked out and then adds books to a dictionary in the following format `dictionary[title] = author`. Then I need to print al of my information in a main function in this format: ""title author pages checkedOut." I basically need to print out the return value of my `__str__()` function in my classes. Here is my code:

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title, author, pages):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.pages = pages
        self.checkedOut = False

    def checked_Out(self):
        print(self.checkedOut)
        return self.checkedOut

    def change_value_of_checkedOut(self):
        if self.checkedOut == False:
            self.checkedOut = True
            print("Switched from False to True.")
        elif self.checkedOut == True:
            self.checkedOut = False
            print("Switched from True to False.")

    def return_pages(self):
        print(self.pages)
        return self.pages

    def return_title(self):
        print(self.title)
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return ("Title: " + self.title + "Author: " + self.author +
                "Pages: " + self.pages + "Checked Out Status: " +
                self.checkedOut)

class Library:
    def __init__(self):
        self.collection = {}

    def addExistingBook(self, book):
        self.collection[book.title] = book.author

    def addNewBook(self, title, author, pages):
        new_book = Book(title, author, pages)
        self.collection[title] = new_book.author

    def change_checked_out_status(self, title):
        if title in self.collection:
            title.change_value_of_checkedOut()
        else:
            print("This book is not in the collection.")

    def __str__(self):
        for myBook in self.collection[myBook]:
            self.collection[myBook]
            self.collection[myBook] = self.author

            # I want to print this return value in my main
        return ("Title: " + self.title + "Author: " + self.author
                + "Pages: " + self.pages + "Checked Out Status: " + self.checkedOut)

def main():
    title = str(input("Enter the title of the book. "))
    author = str(input("Enter the author of the book. "))
    pages = int(input("Enter the number of pages in the book. "))
    myBook = Book(title, author, pages)
    myLib = Library()
    myLib.addExistingBook(myBook)
    myLib2 = Library()
    myLib3 = myLib2.__str__()
    print(myLib3)

main()
```

It seems like something is wrong with the for loop in my `__str__(self)` function in the class Library (the idea is that I want the loop to iterate over ever book in the collection) but I'm not sure what the problem is. Here is the error message that I get:

```
Enter the title of the book. A Tale of Two Cities
Enter the author of the book. Charles Dickens
Enter the number of pages in the book. 434
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Class Programs\lab8.py", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python33\Class Programs\lab8.py", line 68, in main
    myLib3 = myLib2.__str__()
  File "C:\Python33\Class Programs\lab8.py", line 54, in __str__
    for myBook in self.collection[myBook]:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'myBook' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looping over the keys of a dictionary, you should *not* try to pass in a key in the loop statement:

```
def __str__(self):
    for myBook in self.collection:
```

It is unclear what you are trying to do with that loop. You are then accessing `self.collection[myBook]` without doing anything with the return value, then you are *replacing* the value with `self.author` (which doesn't exist on `self`, that is still the library), then you return something completely different as the `__str__()` result.

I *think* you want to create a list of your library books here:

```
def __str__(self):
    return ', '.join('{} - {}'.format(title, author) for title, author in self.collection.items())
```

Now you return a comma-separated list of all titles and authors in your collection.

There are 3 things going on there:

- Using a generator expression, we loop over the dictionary [`.items()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items); this generates `(key, value)` pairs for everything in the dictionary.
- Each key and value is passed to the [`str.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), using the string as a template to put a `-` dash between the title and author pairs stored in your `self.collection` dictionary.
- The whole loop is passed to the [`str.join()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join); this method takes all the strings from the sequence given to it and concatenates them together with `', '` commas between them.

Next, you are creating an *empty* library, then print the output of the `__str__()` method; there is no need to call that explicitly, `print()` does that for you. Do not create a new library, just print the one you already have:

```
myLib = Library()
myLib.addExistingBook(myBook)
print(myLib)
```

Comment: When I change it to what you suggested and run the program, after I put in my input variables, the program just returns None. Like this:

Enter the title of the book. A Tale of Two Cities
Enter the author of the book. Charles Dickens
Enter the number of pages in the book. 434
None

Comment: Got it! Thanks. But can you explain briefly what the return statement you suggested for me means? I've never seen that before.

Comment: [".".join(iteratable)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) joins the iteratable with the string.  For info on `.format` see the cookbook http://mkaz.com/solog/python-string-format

Comment: @IvanLesiv: Added a more detailed explanation with links to method documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change

```
def __str__(self):
        for myBook in self.collection[myBook]:
            self.collection[myBook]
            self.collection[myBook] = self.author
```

to

```
def __str__(self):
        for myBook in self.collection.keys():
            self.collection[myBook]
            self.collection[myBook] = self.author
```

Comment: Python dictionaries do not have a uppercase `.Keys()` method.

Comment: Next, see [my comment on another answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202493/how-do-i-get-the-return-value-of-my-str-function-to-print-in-my-main/16202538?noredirect=1#comment23168034_16202559); you don't actually *need* to use `.keys()`. And as per [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16202535/100297), the rest of the code makes no sense, especially in context of the `__str__` method.